# No Enabled Plugins detected on XULRunner10 for Mac OS

Tags: macos, swt, npapi, xulrunner

For a specific requirement we need to use XULRunner10 for Mac with SWT Application on Mac OS.

We need to communicate  with the detected or enabled NPAPI plugins in XULRunner10.
  We use XULRunner10 for browser rendering.

When we tried 'about:plugins" uri XULRunner10 shows 'No Enabled Plugins found' although Firefox 41 displays all the available plugins on Mac OS Yosemite.

Is there any additional symbolic links needs to created to make XULRunner10 for Mac to detect the plugins ?

Please guide us.